# How to upgrade already developed ASP.NET framework 3.5 project to 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a web application project in asp.net 3.5 frame work(VS 2012). It's working fine in server side. Now I would like to upgrade its version to 4.5 to use the latest updates.  How can I upgrade it?  My friend told that, if I change the version I will lose my web.config file.

How can I upgrade the version without any side effects?

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman, When I change the version I lost some of my web config file contents

Answer (score 1):

Just change the version of your project to .NET 4.5. I don't think there is a special migration path needed.

You won't lose your web.config file all of a sudden. You might need to do some migration of settings (just make a safe copy and see what you need to migrate), but they would most likely be quite easy and only applicable if you use specific parts of the framework for example or a different pipeline mode (but that is just specific to IIS, not your ASP.NET application).

Comment: Unfortunately there are [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes).

Answer (score 0):

There is a MSDN Article [How to: Upgrade an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx) which you can follow.

I think the magic word is "**Visual Studio Conversion Wizard**".